# How should I pull data from a non-CRM database?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a separate non-CRM database that I would like to use for populating an interactive grid within CRM.

This is my first CRM customization so I'm quite new to this..
Should I use a javascript web resource and have a web api to retrieve my data? It seems like this would have the most fluid feel, and I'm already familiar with Javascript and AJAX due to working with MVC.

Or should I use a regular Asp.Net WebForms project?.. I'm not sure if I can put this in CRM (not iframe).

I feel like I'm missing something so any links to resources are appreciated. Thank you for the help!

Comment: you need to store the data inside CRM or only show inside the grid?

Comment: I only need to show the data inside of a grid within the account entity form.

Comment: so you can use an html web resource to pull and display your data, to provide the data is better to use an https web api (to avoid alert for the mixed content)

Comment: I am confused by the second part of your answer. If I use HTML and Javascript I will need to use an web api to get the data to populate the graph.. How else would I get the data from a separate database by only using an html web resource?

Comment: the web api (that will act as a bridge between the data and your js/html code) is the simplest way. I wrote https because if the service is http inside an https organization you will get warnings. an alternative way to retrieve the data is to trigger a plugin and host the data inside a temporary entity, but of course these ways are more complicated (and most of the time useless) than a simple web api

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your help Guido. I really appreciate it!

Comment: I you don't already have the UI for the separate database, would you willing to create a custom CRM entity to hold your data?

Comment: Kye, I did think about that approach but it seems like it would be just as much work, if not more to pull the data into CRM. I would need to do that on a timed schedule or something..